# Is it permissible to call your child ya mohammad?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

Is it permissible to call your child ya mohammad? I am confused. We know that Allah calls prophet mohammad as ya mohammad and to my understanding its going to be only permissible to call someone as only mohammad, not necessarily the exact way that Allah did addressed the prophet as ya mohammad?

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't know Arabic (me too).

In Arabic Ya!(يا)is like Oh! in English.
like Oh Mohammad. Everyone in Arab country call like this. It is just a Language. It is not prohibited to call a child with name Muhammad, Ya Muhammad

Answer (score 3):

***Hadith***

> **Jabir b. 'Abdullah reported that a child was born to a person amongst us and he gave him the name of Muhammad. Thereupon his people said:**
>   We will not allow You to give the name of Muhammad (to your child) after the name of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ). He set forth with his son carrying him on his back and came to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ), and said: Allah's Messenger a son has been born to me and I have given him the name after the name of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), whereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: Give him my name but do not give him my kunya, for I am Qasim in the sense that I distribute (the spoils of war) and the dues of Zakat amongst you. ( [Sahih Muslim Book 38, Hadith 3](http://sunnah.com/muslim/38/3))

and

> A boy was born to one of our men, the Ansar, and he wanted to name him Muhammad. Then Ansari man said, "I took the boy to the Prophet (ﷺ). The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Name your child by my name, but do not name (them) by my Kunya, for I have been made Qasim (i.e., a distributor) to distribute (the booty etc.) amongst you." The narrator, Husain said that the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "I have been sent as a Qasim (i.e., distributor) to distribute (things) amongst you." [The Sub narrator Salim said that he heard Jabir saying that the man wanted to name the boy Al-Qasim, but the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Call (your sons) by my name, but do not name (them) by my Kunya."].. [Sahih al-Bukhari Book 57, Hadith 23](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/57/23)

According to these Hadiths, having a name 'Muhammad' is not forbidding.Now regarding your question, that calling of `Muhammad` as `Ya Muhammad` is permissible or not, so in Arabic `YA`, it means `Oh` or `O`.Just to address/call a person. According to [wiki Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya_Muhammad)- (*Note:Although most of Wiki sources are not authentic*)

> In Saudi Arabia, Yā Muḥammad is used to address a stranger in order to begin a conversation. It is considered one of the polite and respectful ways to address a stranger, as Muhammad is considered as the most respectful name anyone can be called, hence its popularity among Muslims worldwide..

In my opinion it is very beautiful to call your child with `Muhammad` or `Ya Muhammad`. It will surely remind you of the our Prophet (*Peace be upon Him*).

Comment: This isn't restricted on Saudi Arabia it's well known in other Muslim countries too.

Comment: That's why i have mentioned that "*Although most of Wiki sources are not authentic*"

Answer (score 2):

Note "ya Muhammad! يا محمد" means in Arabic "O Muhammad!" it is not a name at all it is a form of "Call نداء" which is introduced by the "يا", so this is an Arabic sentence built with two words which is an expression for Calling somebody! Naming somebody this way doesn't make sense so this isn't recommended to be taken as a name, as names in Islam should make a (good) sense or have a good meaning!

But if your son is named *Muhammad* and you are calling him or want adresse him to tell him something by saying: "ya Muhammad ..." this is correct as far as you are speaking Arabic to him, else it could be nonsense!

On the other hand among the best names we may give a son there's Muhammad, Ahmad ... names like Abdullah, Abdurrahman etc. and names of Prophets like Adam, Ibrahim etc. ..